# CakePHP Burzum/file-storage not able to save files

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, file-storage

I installed the `"burzum/file-storage": "^1.1"` and followed the docs

added this to bootstrap.php:

```
use Cake\Event\EventManager;
use Burzum\FileStorage\FileStorageUtils;
use Burzum\FileStorage\Storage\StorageManager;
use Burzum\FileStorage\Event\LocalFileStorageListener;


StorageManager::config('Local', [
    'adapterOptions' => [TMP, true],
    'adapterClass' => '\Gaufrette\Adapter\Local',
    'class' => '\Gaufrette\Filesystem'
]);

$listener = new LocalFileStorageListener();
EventManager::instance()->on($listener);
```

I've got a table called *Comments* and added this from the Docs

```
$this->hasOne('PdfFiles', [
        'className' => 'Burzum/FileStorage.PdfFiles',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => [
            'PdfFiles.model' => 'Comments'
        ]
    ]);
```

added this form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($comment, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Edit Comment') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->file('pdf_files.file');
        echo $this->Form->input('comment');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

added the table to my database with

```
cake migrations migrate -p Burzum/FileStorage
```

When I send the form the file will not be saved in the *TMP* folder and not in the database.

I try to stick to events. I don't want to use the manual version (this works btw).

What am I missing?

best regards
Sundypha

Comment: Check your php and CakePHP log files. "Not saved" is really nothing meaningful that helps to track down the problem. I bet on that there is a permission issue or something like that. You can debug trough the event listener code as well to find out where it's not saving the file. I know that the plugin works just fine, so it's more or less up to you to find out why the files aren't saved in your environment.

Comment: Yes the Events seems not to fire. In debugKit it's missing, events and the included files. How can I enable logging of your plugin?

Comment: The plugin doesn't use any kind of special logging, read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html

Comment: The events will not be called. And how can I choose which configuration should be used for a model? Is this the `'className' => 'Burzum\FileStorage.CONFIG'`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the events are called, guess you mean the listeners. You haven't attached them correctly or the conditions that they'll process the event data aren't valid. As the documentation says you need to set the `adapter` field field with the name of the config you want to use when saving the file. It will use the config named after the value passed in the adapter field.

Comment: Finally I got a `Error: Class 'Burzum\FileStorage.PdfFiles' not found  
   File C:\xampp\htdocs\stortest\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Locator\TableLocator.php 
   Line: 169`

Comment: Because you copied and pasted code from the examples without understanding of what it does. Hint: Go figure out what the dot notation in className means. Honestly, I don't have the time to teach you the basics of CakePHP and the plugin, if you need personal assistance feel free to hire me. This isn't a problem of the plugin so far.

Comment: Hoenstly your documentation is a huge cluttered spaces (seems like openstack documentaries but they get better). I know that you don't like people who just copy&paste. But at least a simple running example should be given which from one can learn how it works like other plugins https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud-demo-app
trying to figure out how to use your plugin which takes me now 3 days is just waste of time and results in a simpler solution of just using Gaufrette. Your plugin would provide a very nice interface but it's just to hard to use (like other members in SO writing)

Comment: Feel free to use another plugin then. Its free, it's open source, I can use it, many other people are happy as well with it. That's good enough for me. If you want me to improve the documentation fine: Pay me to do it. Writing documentation is not my favourite thing to do for free in my free time. Nor do I think the documentation is cluttered: You just have to read it from the beginning and not jump into the examples and do copy and paste. The documentation of the plugin should be good enough for anyone who understood the basics of CakePHP. I don't think you do if this took you already 3 days.

Comment: @Sundypha do you still need help with this? I struggled with this plugin as well but I did finally got  it to work. burzum is a cool dude and just burnt out on all the noobs using his plugin like myself.

If you still need help message me, i'll give you an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go into details if you still need help with this.

You need to create another table mine is articlesImages yours might be CommentDocs

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;
use Burzum\FileStorage\Model\Table\ImageStorageTable;
class ArticleImagesTable extends ImageStorageTable {


public $actsAs = array(
    'FileStorage.UploadValidator' => array(
        'allowedExtensions' => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png'
        ),
    ),
);
public function upload($article_id, $entity) {

    $entity = $this->patchEntity($entity, [
        'adapter' => 'Local',
        'model' => 'Articles',
        'foreign_key' => $article_id,
    ]);
    return $this->save($entity);

}
    }
    ?>
```

//in my articles table i have

```
$this->hasMany('ArticleImages', [
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
           'conditions' => [
            'model' => 'Articles'
           ]
         ]);
```

//my ArticlesController

```
public function upload($id = null) {

    $entity = $this->Articles->ArticleImages->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $entity = $this->Articles->ArticleImages->patchEntity($entity,$this->request->data);

        if ($this->Articles->ArticleImages->upload($id, $entity)) {
            $this->Flash->set(__('Upload successful!'));
        }            
    }
    $this->set('ArticleImage', $entity);
}
```

Comment: Yours is the better solution than I figured out. Thank you for this solution, which will help most of the ones using this good plugin.

Comment: Do you really have to create a separate Table file for each separate model property you need to have a file attached too? Isn't there a better way, some kind of general class each property can use f.e.